# Excel, =(SUM(...)) with clicking not typing each individual

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=SUM(INDEX(A:A,5*(ROW()-1)+1):INDEX(A:A,5*(ROW()-1)+5))

this code splits 100 rows in 1 column and adds 5 by 5
examples: 1+2+3+4+5
6+7+8+9+10
and so on...

I need to do the same but from cell F4 to F1127, and I need the step to be by 4 not by 5.
how please?

Answer (score 1):

in **D1** enter:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,5*(ROW()-1)+1):INDEX(A:A,5*(ROW()-1)+5))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

If you need a VBA approach:

```
Sub adds()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    k = 1
    
    For i = 1 To 96 Step 5
        j = i + 4
        Cells(k, "D").Formula = "=SUM(A" & i & ":A" & j & ")"
        k = k + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: hello, thank you, what if I need to do a step by 4 from F4 to F1127? How will the code change?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SUM(INDEX($A:$A,SEQUENCE(5,,(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1)*5+1,1)))
```

Comment: hello, thank you, what if I need to do a step by 4 from F4 to F1127? How will the code change?